# totally bounded question

Tags: real-analysis

Given: If (x,p) is totally bounded and E is subset of X,

prove that (E,p) is totally bounded

we know that  Every subset of a totally bounded space is a totally bounded set; but even if a space is not totally bounded, some of its subsets still will be.

how do we prove this?

Comment: What exactly are $(E,p)$/$(X,p)$?

Comment: @SomeMathStudent Metric spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A space $X$ is called totally bounded if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there's a finite numbers of sets $U_n$ with diameter (meaning $\sup_{x,y\in U_n}{p(x-y)}$) less than $\varepsilon$,  such that $X\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n{U_i}$.

Now, if you take a look at this definition. We know that there is such a set $U_n$ for our original space $X$. We know that $X$ is covered by this set. And we need to find a set $\overline{U}_n$ with the same properties, such that $E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n{\overline{U}_n}$.

Now, do you think you can continue from here? Is there possibly a trivial solution for your set $\overline{U}_n$?

*Note that this is the - for me - usual definition used in topology. If I remember back to my first Analysis courses, though, I am not sure how exactly we introduced totally bounded spaces - there are various equivalent definitions. If this is not the one given, you could try to prove that it is equivalent, or just comment.*

Answer (score 0):

What does it means that $X$ is totally bounded? It means, that given $\varepsilon > 0$ then there exist some finitely many points $x_1, \dots, x_n$ all in $X$ such that $X \subseteq \cup_{i =1}^n B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)$ (this  is sometimes called a "$\varepsilon $ net"), where $ B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)= \{ x\in X \colon \rho(x,x_i) < \varepsilon \}$.

From this is pretty obvious that every $x \in X$ has to fall in at least one $B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)$ .

Now you have $E \subset X$ and $X$ totally bounded.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, because of what we talked before there is some $\varepsilon/2$ net of $n$ points all in $X$, but we wanted points in $E$!

Now because $E \subset X$ given a $B_{\varepsilon/2}(x_i)$, this might containt points of $E$ or no, if it doesnt we wont fret about that ball but if it does contain at least one point of $E$, we'll take it, one for each ball that has. 
Eventualy, we'll get finitely many points in $E$, $e_1, \dots, e_m$ with $m < n$. Now, I claim that $E \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(e_1)$ is a $\varepsilon$ net of E, why? well, if $x \in E$ then $x \in B_{\varepsilon/2}(x_i)$ for some $i$, but we also have $e_j \in B_{\varepsilon/2}(x_i)$ for some j. Now $\rho (e_j, x) \leq \rho(e_j, x_i) + \rho(x_i,x) < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon$, wich means that $x \in B_{\varepsilon}(e_j)$.